# Download URL in Firebase not displaying in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q38fM.png)I am getting the download URL from the image I uploaded to firebase storage. But once I put the url as a uri in an image tag in React Native, it does not display. How do I fix this?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q38fM.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3TQ7.png)

[Trying to display download url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXJD9.png)

Comment: Can you share your code that is not working as intended?

Comment: @Dharmaraj just did!

Comment: Also, I know the function for downloading the url is working because I am able to console.log() it. I think the image not rendering has something to do with it being downloaded first to the local device.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. `console.log()` your download URL to confirm that it is a valid string
2. try hard-coding that same (valid) URL into your `<Image src={...}>` to see that it works/doesn't work (i.e. eliminate the asynchronous nature of setting state variable values)
3. ensure that `theuser.updateP....()` (can't see the function name in the photo) is synchronous, and if not then ensure you are calling the asynchronous function correctly
4. just before the `return()` that outputs the `<Image>`, add a `console.log(Profilepic)` to ensure it has the value you expect it to have
5. what is calling `getData()` ?
6. I would NOT be using the photoURL (or any other fields other than UID) from the Authentication object.  Instead, as Firebase suggests, move your "user profile" information into a real database (Firestore, RTDB, or some other system).  The "profile information" in Authentication is of limited use and there are major delays between calls to update the data before the information becomes available for use.